# Q learning in a stochastic environment

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Most examples I have seen about Q learning, are performed in a deterministic world. For example, in the traditional grid world, the agent can finally do the path searching by exploring and exploiting the environment with a reward function without knowing the transition probability function.

$$Q(s,a) = Q(s,a) + a*[ Reward + discount * Max Q(s',a') - Q(s,a)] $$

Now suppose the grid is a stochastic environment, an agent can move up/left/right with 1/3 probability. How can I program the Q learning, does that mean that in calculating the $Max Q(s',a')$,
$$Max Q(s',a') = Max [ P(up)*Q(s',up)  , P(left) *Q(s',down) ,   P(right) * Q(s, right)]?$$

Comment: Welcome to the site, @user824624. I edited your question to add formatting and to make the English clearer. Make sure it still says what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Q-learning also permits an agent to choose an action stochastically (according to some distribution).   In this case, the reward is the expected reward given that distribution of actions.  I think this fits your case above.

Q-learning also permits actions that may fail.  Hence, $Q(s, Left)$ might lead you to a state $s'$ that is not the to the left $s$ (e.g. the action "fails" with some probability).  In that case, the model (MDP, table of Q-values, automaton) will encode the possibility of failure directly and no distributions or expected values are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no exploration done in calculating the Q-value as you described it above. Exploration happens only if you introduce a certain probability with which a random action is performed. Calculating the Q-value only *enables* to choose the action maximizing the Q-value given the current state.

In effect, this means choosing the state-action pair $(s, a) $ with the highest Q-value such that $s $ is the current state and $a $ is one of the possible actions.

Transition probabilities are considered implicitly, as the Q-value adapts to those transitions that actually happen--whether intentionally chosen or randomly selected via exploration or the stochastic environment. As Tim mentioned, you can also choose actions probabilistically. In the best case, however, this is *as good as* deterministically choosing the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, no assumption is made Q-learning regarding the transition function  other than that it exists and is a probability distribution. The definition of a Q-function is given by
$$Q(s, a) = \mathbb{E}_{\tau \sim (\pi, p)}[r(s, a) + \gamma v_\pi(S') | S_t=s, A_t=a]\;$$
where $v_\pi$ is the value function of policy $\pi$, and $\tau$ is the trajectory which we assume to be generated according to the policy $\pi$ and transition function $p$.

What this essentially means is that the Q-function is the expected (discounted) returns of taking action $a$ in state $s$ and following $\pi$ thereafter to generate the rest of the trajectory until termination. Now, $\pi$ is used to generate actions whilst the transition function $p$ determines the state transition dynamics, i.e. it gives us $p(s' | s, a)$ (that is, the probability of transitioning to state $s'$ given that we took action $a$ in state $s$).

You can see that this definition, as I stated at the beginning of the answer, makes no underlying assumptions about whether or not $p$ is stochastic or deterministic.

> Now suppose the grid is a stochastic environment, an agent can move up/left/right with 1/3 probability.

What you are describing here is not totally clear (at least to me), but I would not describe this as an instance of a stochastic environment. A clearer example would be that, if the action 'up' is taken, then with probability $x$ the agent actually moves up, and with probability $1-x$ the agent moves instead to the right (for some $x \in (0, 1)$).